# Creating Objects Dynamically on a frame

Tags: delphi

I have two scenarios. One works, one does not. The first (the one that works) invloves a scrollbox sitting directly on a form that when a button is pushed it executes this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin
 DrawPanel;
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawPanel;
begin
BuildPanel; //Resides on a seperate unit code pasted below

TestPanel.Height := 40;
TestPanel.Width := 100;
TestPanel.Left := Trunc(ScrollBox1.Width / 2) - Trunc(TestPanel.Width / 2);
TestPanel.Top := Trunc(ScrollBox1.Height / 2) - Trunc(TestPanel.Height / 2);
TestPanel.Visible := True;
TestPanel.Parent := ScrollBox1;

end;

unit Unit3;

interface

uses ExtCtrls;

Var
 TestPanel : Tpanel;

Procedure BuildPanel; 

implementation

procedure BuildPanel;
begin
 TestPanel := TPanel.Create(Nil);
end;

end.
```

The code is identical except for a small difference in the second scenario. The scrollbox sits on a frame that is added to the Templates palette and then dropped down on the form. The button click calls:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
TestFrame.DrawPanel;
end;

procedure TTestFrame.DrawPanel;
begin
 BuildPanel; //Still points to the unit3 code above

   TestPanel.Height := 40;
   TestPanel.Width := 100;
   TestPanel.Left := Trunc(ScrollBox1.Width / 2) - Trunc(TestPanel.Width / 2);
   TestPanel.Top := Trunc(ScrollBox1.Height / 2) - Trunc(TestPanel.Height / 2);
   TestPanel.Visible := True;
   TestPanel.Parent := ScrollBox1;
end;
```

However the panel will not display in the scrollbox that sits on the frame, when triggered at runtime. I'm not really sure why, can anybody help out? I hope I was specific enough in my question, let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks in advance.

Here's all the code in order.....Hopefully it make it more clear:

```
//This is the form 
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Unit2, Unit3;

type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
 Button1: TButton;
 TTestFrame1: TTestFrame;
 ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
 Button2: TButton;
 procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
 procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
 procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
private
 { Private declarations }
 TestFrame: TTestFrame;
 Procedure DrawPanel;
public
 { Public declarations }
end;

var
 Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TestFrame.DrawPanel;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DrawPanel;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 TestFrame.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TestFrame := TTestFrame.Create(Form1);
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawPanel;
begin
 BuildPanel;

 TestPanel.Height := 40;
 TestPanel.Width := 100;
 TestPanel.Left := Trunc(ScrollBox1.Width / 2) - Trunc(TestPanel.Width / 2);
 TestPanel.Top := Trunc(ScrollBox1.Height / 2) - Trunc(TestPanel.Height / 2);
 TestPanel.Visible := True;
 TestPanel.Parent := ScrollBox1;

end;

end.

//This is the frame
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, 
  Dialogs, Unit3;

type
 TTestFrame = class(TFrame)
 ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
private
 { Private declarations }
public
 { Public declarations }
  Procedure DrawPanel;
end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TTestFrame }

procedure TTestFrame.DrawPanel;
begin
 BuildPanel;

 TestPanel.Height := 40;
 TestPanel.Width := 100;
 TestPanel.Left := Trunc(ScrollBox1.Width / 2) - Trunc(TestPanel.Width / 2);
 TestPanel.Top := Trunc(ScrollBox1.Height / 2) - Trunc(TestPanel.Height / 2);
 TestPanel.Visible := True;
 TestPanel.Parent := ScrollBox1;

end;
end.

//This is the unit that mocks my data structure
//In reality it creates an Array of Tpanel that is part of a class.                                                                                                         
unit Unit3;

interface

uses ExtCtrls;

Var
 TestPanel : Tpanel;

Procedure BuildPanel;

implementation

procedure BuildPanel;
begin
 TestPanel := TPanel.Create(Nil);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Bit hard to follow with all the code scattered here and there. I do wonder why you feel the need to use global variables. Any chance of a complete program? All the code in a single unit?

Comment: This is a mock up of what I am actually doing. That's why I am using global variables, I am simply testing the Theory. I can post all the code but as mentioned it is between a Form, a Frame, and a separate unit that handles the data structure. I code post the code in it's entirety though if that would help.

Comment: You are creating the TestFrame, but not assigning a parent.

Comment: That was it! thanks so much bummi!

Comment: Instead of doing `trunc(scrollbox.width / 2)` you can do `scrollbox.width div 2`.

Comment: Thank you Wouter! I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot to assign a `parent` to your dynamic created TestFrame.

Comment: Thanks again bummi, I knew I had to be over looking something.